# Validation - is rendered item valid xhtml - Exception

Tags: validation, xhtml, sitecore, sitecore7

When I do Validation on a page in Sitecore 7, the validation throws an exception :

```
The Page represented by the item 'home/about-us' failed to render properly. The error was     :
The remote server returned an error : (500) Internal Server Error
```

I didnt expect the page to render as a valid XHTML, but I also did not expect an exception by validation.

Does anyone have an idea, why this exception is thrown?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered this issue and found it wasn't that the page mark-up was invalid rather, that the Sitecore validator doesn't handle errors well enough to provide useful feedback to the end user.

**How the XHTML validator works (out of the box)**

1. Build up a friendly URL of the current item (with extra parameters to handle language, device etc.).
2. Create a web request with the combined URL and retrieve this page (this is where the error most likely comes from).
3. Download the response and send it off to W3C Validator (there is more logic around here however, it's probably not the cause of OP's issue).
4. Return validation information to the user.

**So why does it break?**

If the web request above fails the validator will also fail however, it won't really give you a detailed reason why (you get the exception message when you really need the inner exception message). It also fails to log anything to the Sitecore logs.

**How to fix the XHTML validator issues**

You're server *probably* isn't configured correctly to allow for web requests to itself. Here are some quick ideas that may help you.

1. Check that you have valid SSL certificates if you're using them (self-signed won't work).
2. Check that you've set the server proxy correctly.
3. Check that your server is not URL Re-writing the requests in a strange way.
4. Create a new implementation of the Sitecore.Data.Validators.ItemValidators.FullPageXHtmlValidator based on the original, update the validator item in Sitecore to use you're new validator and then run a debugger over it.
5. Disable the XHtml validator (this would depend on the requirements for your implementation).

Answer (score 1):

(500) Internal Server Error is a general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server and the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. This most probably means that it is an issue with the page or site's programming, nothing you have anything to do with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, does the page load when you just try to render it or does that crash?

If that works, the next thing to check is that if you look in the web.config, there is a url that is specified the validation check.  See what  you have listed.  This should be the default.

```xml
<setting name="HtmlEditor.ValidatorServiceUrl" value="http://validator.w3.org/check" />
```

If it's not set to that value, put that in and try again.  If you are able to get to that page, see if it validates manually.  If its able to check manually and return a successful result, then I'd suggest putting in a ticket to Sitecore support.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens when you are trying to validate an item in a local IIS environment. The W3 validator cannot access your local web application.